# XPathException: No expression before quantifier - but I can't find its cause

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I am working on an XSLT transformation from XML to CSV. As the XML is huge I work on skipping nodes that match an entry in a blacklist, defined in the stylesheet.
I am using Saxon 9 HE as XSLT engine, called from within Eclipse.
I receive a stacktrace like this:

```
JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error at char 34 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/Public/workspace/TraceToCSV.xsl; Line#: 97; Column#: 31
; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/Public/workspace/TraceToCSV.xsl; Line#: 97; Column#: 31
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Syntax error at char 34 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier
    at net.sf.saxon.regex.ARegularExpression.<init>(ARegularExpression.java:57)
    at net.sf.saxon.java.JavaPlatform.compileRegularExpression(JavaPlatform.java:326)
```

and the call in my stylesheet is:

```
...
<xsl:when test="$blacklist/entry[matches(text(), $textdata, 'i')]">
    <xsl:message>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$textdata" />
        <xsl:text>' is blacklisted</xsl:text>
    </xsl:message>
</xsl:when>
```

where $blacklist is defined in an earlier location similar to

```
<xsl:variable name="blacklist">
    <entry>^first expression$</entry>
    <entry>^second expression$</entry>
    <entry>^and so on$</entry>
    <entry>^with some digits \d+$</entry>
</xsl:variable>
```

The error message is confusing because 'at char 34 in regular expression' makes no sense since they are all shorter.

The stylesheet filters out quite a few of the entries before it fails, so it must basically be right. My only though is that there is a problem with escaping `\d+` differently, as this is the only regex having a quantifier, but I tried already with a double backslash and it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the [matches](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) call - input and pattern were in the wrong order.